# mysql debian-start[190181]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, systemd, mariadb

I am trying to set up MariaDB server under xubuntu 20.04 and import all the db's I had previously on another machine under xubuntu 18 (following the notes I took when doing it there coming from opensuse).

The installed mariadb has datadir in `/var/lib/mysql`, and contains only a "null" msyql db with a root user with no password (as tested entering as `sudo mysql -u root mysql` which requires my personal passwd password).

I stopped the MariaDB server from the system installation, edited the `mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` with my few changes (chief of them is that the datadir is `/elsewhere/Mysql`), then
I rsynced all my databases from the previous machine (I had prepared also mysql dumps,but since the MariaDB version is the same, I thought this was easier).

Then a `systemctl start mariadb` returns with no error but a `systemctl status mariadb` shows that the post-processing debian-start has given the error reported in the subject.

MariaDB looks running OK. I can enter with the mysql client in all my personal databases using my old mysql password, and I can also enter as mysql root using my old mysql root password. Those passwords are of course not the same as the passwd ones.

So I can work normally, only there is this slightly disturbing message from debian-start as if it was trying to login using no  root password (which succeeds using the original `mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`).

This did not occur on Ubuntu 18 (there I had to set `ProtectHome=false`, but apparently this is not required on 20)

Any way to get rid of the annoying message, or should I just live with it since all the rest works ?

Comment: Can I confirm that you've manually installed a *Debian* version of MariaDB on Xubuntu rather than use the default packages that are available in the repositories? If so, you may need to use `sudo mysql_fix_privilege_tables` to ensure that everything is properly up to date and migrated.

Comment: I use the bundled package loaded with synaptic. I just repointed datadir elsewhere and put there all my old databases.